# Excel macro while loop applying to a whole column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet in which there is data in columns PO through PX. For each row in in these columns, I want to perform the following WHILE loop calculation and assign the answer in the active cell:

If the value in the header row (i.e., row 1) <= the value in column QJ of the current row, then add up the values in that row, and enter the sum in column QK.

Apply the same logic to all rows.

The data looks something like this:

[image: data]

I've written the below code, which works for Row 2, but how can I apply this to the entire column (for the rest of 563 rows) ?

```vb
Sub test()

i = Range("QJ2")
Dim intx As Integer

Do While i > 0 And i <= Range("QJ2")
    If i = Range("QJ2") Then
        intx = WorksheetFunction.Hlookup(i, Range("PO1:PX565"), 2, False)
    Else
        intx = intx + WorksheetFunction.Hlookup(i, Range("PO1:PX565"), 2, False)
    End If

    i = i - 1
Loop
ActiveCell.Value = intx
End Sub
```

I don't know how to apply the same code to all the rows within the same column.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you want here, if any of the header values in PO1:PX1 <= QJi (with i being current row), you need the sum of POi:PXi placed in QKi? Or only the values that are <= QJi ? As example in your first data-row: QJ2 = 5 and since QJ2 <= 10 so there's definitely a PO1:PX1 lower than it which makes you sum up PO5:PX5 <-------> or PO5:PS5 would be summed up because PS1<=QJ2

Comment: I read your question but I can't say I understand it. I suspect you need a simple formula and not VBA. Can you tell me what values you expect in cells QK2 to QK8?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, Richard below answered it for me - I didn't need to use VBA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused too, but I think what you're asking is this, in English:

Sum every cell in the row, where the value in Row 1 for that column is `<=` the value in column QK for that row. In other words, when `QJ2 = 5`, `QK2` = sum of all columns with `Row 1 <= 5`. So `QK2 = 28` as a result.

If that interpretation is correct, put a formula like this in QK2 (I've written just the first 5 terms, you'll have to extend it following the same pattern; replace the `...` with the remaining terms). QK2 should have 10 IF() terms when you're done. Then copy QK2 down column QK.

```
=IF(PO$1<=$QJ2,PO2,0)+IF(PP$1<=$QJ2,PP2,0)+IF(PQ$1<=$QJ2,PQ2,0)+IF(PQ$1<=$QJ2,PQ2,0)+IF(PR$1<=$QJ2,PR2,0) + ...
```

If my interpretation is not correct, show what values should be in column QK. And please provide it as a spreadsheet rather than a picture, so we can copy and paste.